# Programmatically passing # in URL to a browser

Tags: firefox, url, pdf, google-chrome, escaping

I need to pass the character `#` as part of the URL to the browser and open it programatically. When I do the following:

```
google-chrome path_to_some_file.pdf#view=Fit
```

The opened page on the browser is `path_to_some_file.pdf%23view=Fit`, which is not the intended URL. When I manually delete `%23` and type `#` in the address bar of the browser, then it works. How can I pass the character `#` to a browser programmatically?

Comment: Interesting. It is being automatically escaped... I wonder if perhaps it's not possible in this case?

Comment: @pst That may be so. The problem is that the pdf specification tells me to put a `#`: http://floatboxjs.com/content/parameters.pdf#page=8

Comment: You may want to try this on the Superuser stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a fully qualified `file:///` URL in order to include `?` query or `#` hash strings.

More details:

The following approach works in IE10, Firefox 28, and Chrome 36.

If you are doing this from a batch file in Windows with any of those browsers, you can use backward slashes in the path as long as you prefix with `file:///`. E.g., `file:///C:/blah/blah/file.pdf#etc` is the proper URL, but if yours ends up formatted `file:///C:\blah\blah\file.pdf#etc`, that will work too.

Here is how you can get the full path using a batch file.

```
file:///%CD%/file.pdf#blah
```

will resolve to a file relative to the working directory (usually the batch file's directory unlike explicitly changed via command prompt or programmatically).

```
file:///%~dp0/file.pdf#blah
```

will resolve to a file relative to the batch file's directory. I usually go with this.

You can use `../` to navigate up relative to the batch file's directory. The resulting URL should still work fine.

If you are using something a bit more robust than batch files, you can translate all the `\`s into `/`s to create a proper URL.

E.g., in .NET, I think you can do `new Uri("C:\blah\file.pdf")`, and it'll give you a file URI (I think, not sure), which you can then grab and append the hash onto it.